# VEIKK A50 graphics tablet configuration

Tags: drivers, graphics-tablet, stylus

Recently I bought a VEIKK A50 Graphics Tablet.

The mouse is detected automatically but I am not finding any way to
configure pen buttons or pressure sensitivity.

I installed drivers using [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzazndBhrMg&t=225s), but there is no improvement.

How can I get this working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ***secure boot*** worked for me.